# '$' regex python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to understand how '$' works in the re module of `python 3.6`.

The python documentation says,`'$' Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string...`, which I do not completely understand.

Could you please give me a few basic examples of $'s functionality in`re.match`?

Comment: Why don't you google for "python regex end of string newline"?

Comment: I cannot find an example in the Reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` character always matches the end of the input string.

In Multi-line mode (e.g. when `re.M` is passed as a flag to one of the `re` functions), it also matches the end of each line of a multiple line input, just before the newline character.

You want an example with `re.match`:

```
some_string = "foo bar baz"
if re.match("foo.*baz$", some_string):
    print("Starts with foo and ends with baz") # this will be printed
```

The `$` character in the pattern here ensures that the `baz` that gets matched occurs right at the end of the input string. That pattern wouldn't match a string like `"foo baz bar"`, since even though `baz` occurs, it isn't at the end of the input.

It's not usually useful to call `re.match` with the multi-line flag set. Instead, you'd more commonly do that with something like `re.findall`:

```
multi_line_string = """
foo
bar
foobar
barrel"""

for match in re.findall("^bar$", re.M):
    print("bar is whole line") # this will get printed only once
```

The `^` and `$` characters in the pattern given to `re.findall` make sure that `bar` is the whole contents of the line that gets matched. Without them, `foobar` and `barrel` would also match.